# Sharing config files between nodes in a Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I have a 3-node hadoop cluster and I was wondering as to how I can share the config files (like hadoop-env.sh) among all 3 nodes. Do I have to update them manually in each of the node or is it enough if I change it in the Master node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to update the configuration manually (or through a management utility) on each node that requires the change.